# Mark Core Data entries as Favourites SWIFTUI

Tags: json, core-data, swiftui

I am working on an app that stores posts from on-line Json to CoreData for offline content. It is a Real Estate Listings app where users sell and rent properties.

So far i accomplish to save fethed listings in CoreData but I can not implement "Add to Favourites" for the existing entries. I use NSPredicate to filter the listings types .in different views

1. I have created a entity "Listing" [Core Data - Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Bvg.png)
2. And a "Favorite" entity [Core Data - Favorites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGkuZ.png)

My question is: How can i achieve "Add to Favourite"

Option A: Save the "is favourite" listing one more time in another Entity.

Option B: Create  in the "Listing" Entity another "is favourite" property and keep it in Core Data as long as is favourite?

// Here is my Listing Model.swift

```
struct ListingModel:  Hashable, Decodable, Encodable, Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var title : String
    var category : String
    var name : String
    var image : String
    var publishdate : String
    var saleprice : Int = 0
    var rentprice : Int = 0
    var listingtype : String
    var latitude : Double!
    var longitude : Double!
    
}
```

```swift
//  JSONViewModel.swift


import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class JSONViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var listings: [ListingModel] = []
  //  @Published var tags :[Tags] = []
    // saving Json to Core Data...
    
    func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        listings.forEach { (data) in
            
            let entity = Listing(context: contex)
            entity.title = data.title
            entity.name = data.name
            entity.category = data.category
            entity.image = data.image
            entity.publishdate = data.publishdate
            entity.tagline = data.tagline
            entity.content = data.content
            entity.coverimage = data.coverimage
            entity.saleprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.saleprice))
            entity.rentprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rentprice))
            entity.phone = data.phone
            entity.email = data.email
            entity.area = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.area))
            entity.rooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rooms))
            entity.beds = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.beds))
            entity.bathrooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.bathrooms))
            entity.expires = data.expires
            entity.adresa = data.adresa
            entity.listingtype = data.listingtype
            entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
            entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))

        }
        
//        }
        // saving all pending data at once
        
        do{
            try contex.save()
           
            print("success")
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        
        let url = "https://... my api adress"
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.addValue("swiftui2.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "field")
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, _) in
            
            guard let jsonData = data else{return}
            
            // check for errors
            
            let response = res as! HTTPURLResponse
            // checking by status code
            
            if response.statusCode == 404 {
                print("error Api Errror")
            }
            
            // fetching JSON Data ..
            do {
                let listings = try JSONDecoder().decode([ListingModel].self, from: jsonData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  
                    self.listings = listings
                    
                    self.saveData(contex: context)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }

  // try to extend the function 

func addListingToFavourites(favouritelisting:ListingModel) {
    addRecordToFavourites(favouritelisting:favouritelisting.title)
}
func isListingFavourite(favouritelisting:ListingModel) -> Bool {
    if let _ = fetchRecord(favouritelisting:favouritelisting.title) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func removeListingFromFavourites(favouritelisting:ListingModel) {
    removeRecordFromFavourites(favouritelisting:favouritelisting.title)
}

func toggleFavourite(favouritelisting:ListingModel) {
    if isListingFavourite(favouritelisting: favouritelisting) {
        removeListingFromFavourites(favouritelisting: favouritelisting)
    }
    else {
        addListingToFavourites(favouritelisting: favouritelisting)
    }
}
}
```

and i created also extension JSONViewModel:

```swift
extension JSONViewModel {
    
    private func addRecordToFavourites(favouritelisting:String) {
        guard let context = managedContext else {return}
        if let record = fetchRecord(favouritelisting:favouritelisting) {
            print("record \(record) already exists")
            return
        }
        
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Favourite",
                                                in: context)!
        let favourite = NSManagedObject(entity:entity, insertInto:context)
        favourite.setValue(favouritelisting, forKeyPath:"favouritelisting")
        
        do {
          try context.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
          print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        self.changed = true
    }
    
    private func fetchRecord(favouritelisting:String) -> Favourite? {
        guard let context = managedContext else {return nil}
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Favourite>(entityName: "Favourite")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "favouritelisting == %@", favouritelisting)
        
        if let users = try? context.fetch(request) {
            if users.count > 0 {
                return users[0]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    private func removeRecordFromFavourites(favouritelisting:String) {
        guard let context = managedContext else {return}
        if let record = fetchRecord(favouritelisting:favouritelisting) {
            context.delete(record)
            self.changed = true
        }
    }
}
```

::: Am i on the wright way? still i don't know it this what i should do!

Please find bellow Latest listingsView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct latestListings: View {
    @StateObject var jsonModel = JSONViewModel()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    @FetchRequest(entity: Listing.entity(),
    sortDescriptors:
    [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Listing.publishdate, ascending: false)])
    
    
    
    var results : FetchedResults<Listing>
    
    var textHeight: CGFloat = 60
    var fullWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var cardWidthHalf: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3
    var spacing: CGFloat = 10
    var viewHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
    
    @State private var isError = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack {
               
                    HStack {
                        Text("Latest Listings")
                            .modifier(textSectionTitle())
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink (destination: AllListingsVertical()) {
                            ViewMoreButton()
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
            Divider()
                .modifier(dividerStyle())
               
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "wand.and.stars.inverse")
                    .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                Text("Manualy download listings to device storage. Useful for offline use.")
                    .modifier(textSectionTagline())
            }
            }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .padding(.bottom, 0)
            
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                
                
                
                HStack {
                    // checkin if core data exists
                    if results.isEmpty{
                        
                        if jsonModel.listings.isEmpty{
                            
                            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    ProgressView()
                        
                                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color("dinamicPillsGrass")))
                                        .scaleEffect(2, anchor: .center)
                                        // fetching data
                                        .onAppear(perform: {
                                            jsonModel.fetchData(context: context)
                                            
                                    })
                                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            }.modifier(cardHeight())
                            
                            // when array is clear indicator appears
                            // as result data is fetched again
                        }
                        else{
                            
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                
                                
                                ForEach(jsonModel.listings,id: \.self){listing in
                                    NavigationLink (destination: CardDetailView(listing: listing)) {
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            CardViewOrizontal(listing: listing)
                                        }
                                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                    // display fetched Json Data..
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    else{
                        // results.prefix(?) unde ? cata articole sa arate
                       HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(results.prefix(10)){listing in
                                NavigationLink (destination: CardDetailView(fetchedData: listing)) {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        CardViewOrizontal(fetchedData: listing)
                                    }
                                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 15)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    // update finish
                    
                }.padding(.top, 10)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                   
                
            })
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                
                Button(action: {

                    // clearing data in core data..

                    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
                      //
                        do{
                            jsonModel.listings.removeAll()
                            results.forEach { (listing) in context.delete(listing) }
                            try context.save()
                        }
                        catch{
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        print("Network is connected")
                        self.isError = false
                       
                        
                    } else {

                        print("Network is not connected")
                        self.isError = true
                    }
                    
                    

                }, label: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down")
                            .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                        Text("Update")
                            .modifier(textSectionTagline())
                    }
                    .padding(5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    .background(Color("blueLeading"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .modifier(shadowPills())
                }).alert(isPresented: $isError) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Network is not connected"),
                          message: Text("WiFi or Cellular not availible. You can still browse offline content!"),
                          dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
            
            
            }.frame(width: fullWidth)
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 60)
        .frame(width: fullWidth)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("dinamicGray1"), Color("dinamicGray2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .padding(.top, -50)
        .modifier(shadowSection())
    }
}
```

And CardDetailView

```html
//
//  CardDetailView.swift
//  WebyCoreData
//
//  Created by Marius Geageac on 20.12.2020.
//

import SwiftUI
import KingfisherSwiftUI
import MapKit




struct CardDetailView: View {
  // noul liked
    var fullWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var halfScreenH: CGFloat =  UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
    
    @ObservedObject var settingsVM = SettingsViewModel()
    
    @State private var isVisible = false

    var listing: ListingModel?
    var fetchedData: Listing?
    // Modifiers
    var cardWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var imageWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    /// map
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: listing == nil ? fetchedData!.latitude : listing!.latitude,
            longitude: listing == nil ? fetchedData!.longitude : listing!.longitude)
    }
   
    let paddingPills: CGFloat = 5
    let textSizePills: CGFloat = 14
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(listing == nil ? fetchedData!.title! : listing!.title)
                                .modifier(textSectionTitle())
                        }
                        Divider()
                            .modifier(dividerStyle())
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                                .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                            Text(listing == nil ? fetchedData!.tagline! : listing!.tagline)
                                .modifier(textSectionTagline())
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom, 0)
                    if self.fetchedData!.isFavorite == false {
                    Button(action: {
                        fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle()
                      }) {
                        Image(systemName: "heart.circle")
                            .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                    }.padding()
                    }
                    else {
                        Button(action: {
                            fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle()
                          }) {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.circle.fill")
                                .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                        }.padding()
                    }
        
            }
                
        
        
    }
}
```

import SwiftUI

struct Favorites: View {

```
@StateObject var jsonModel = JSONViewModel()

var cardWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30
var fullWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

//   @StateObject var jsonModel = JSONViewModel()
@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var context

```
// Fetching Data From Core Data..
@FetchRequest(entity: Listing.entity(), sortDescriptors:
```

//    [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Listing.publishdate, ascending: false)])
[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Listing.publishdate, ascending: false),],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == %@" ,  NSNumber(value: true)))

```
var results : FetchedResults<Listing>



var body: some View {

    
    ScrollView(.vertical) {

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(results){listing in
                        NavigationLink (destination: CardDetailView(fetchedData: listing)) {
                            VStack {
                                CardView(fetchedData: listing)
                            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                             .modifier(cardHeight())
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }

        }
       
    }.padding(.top, 20)
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
           
            allListingsTitlePill() // Title
        
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "heart.circle.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .regular))
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally just add another property in your listings entity called isFavourite and set it to a boolean. set it initially to false.

Then when you are doing your fetch requests, you can only show favourites using a predicate like this.

`let predicateIsFavourite = NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == %@", NSNumber(value: true))`

and in lists / ForEach, you display whether it is a favourite and use a button to toggle it being a favourite.
The toggle would just set the value of isFavourite to true (let me know if you would like some code for that but looking at your question, it seems like you know how to do that)

Comment: I thin typically this would be it's own question (as it helps others search when they are facing a similar issue). I don't think your suggested code would work as presumably fetchedData is the full array of listings. you'd want to update the individual listing entry by passing the listing object to a function. Could you share your view code please and then I can probably be more specific with my guidance.

Comment: try:

fetchedData!.toggle()
   do {
      try context.save()
   }
   catch{
      print(error)
   }

Comment: oh and try this for your heart button instead of the big if statement that you have: 

Button(action: {
   fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle()
}) {
   Image(systemName:  fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle")
      .modifier(textSectionIcon())
}.padding()

Comment: it's called a Ternary Operator

Comment: you need to add your context environment object into detail view like you have in listings view

 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

Comment: i updated the button - give no error instead i get: Thread 1: "keypath isFavourite not found in entity Listing". when i visit the Favorites filteres view on the Iphone simulator

Comment: what have you called the new Boolean you have created in core data?

Comment: just double check your spelling of favorite. Your error has a U in it and your code does not. (assuming your code is something like:

Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() do { try context.save() } catch{ print(error) } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding()

Comment: you are wright - there was a misstype error. Works like charm. Thank you so much friend!

Comment: The FavoriteView is updating and showing all Favorite listings. But are not persistent. when i restart the app gets empty,

Comment: that's strange, can you show me the code you ended up with for your favourite button?

Comment: Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding()

Comment: sorry, yes that was my fault. When I told you about the ternary operator, I used your old code when I should have updated it.

Comment: Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() do { try context.save() } catch{ print(error) } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding()

Comment: try that instead

Comment: for the last button you mention Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() do { try context.save() } catch{ print(error) } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding()                              i get this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: also for this: Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() do { try context.save() } catch{ print(error) } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding() i get this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: let me have a look. It's a little difficult to debug as I don't have your core data objects in my Xcode.

Comment: Auto corection did this: Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle() ; <-- HERE
                            do { try context.save() } catch{ print(error) } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle") .modifier(textSectionIcon()) }.padding()

Comment: looks like now the data is persisting! :)

Comment: yeah, I think it just needed the bit that starts with "do {" on a separate line. It is in my code but when I paste into this comments section - everything gets put on same line

Comment: ; semi colon does the same thing

Comment: that's odd. You didn't change any of that code did you? All the changes we've made today are on the detailView, is that right?

Comment: yes obly there! i will do it from the beginning carefully! Can i do the same adding to favorite a filtrr query from coredata? Lets say user select some filtersand end up with appartments with 2 rooms and price 100k, can i use the same trategy to save this filter in a list?

Comment: Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: for that, you would probably want a separate entity (as it's not related to an individual letting) and have properties like min rooms, max rooms, min price, max price. Then you can have your list of saved searches and once you click on one - it's used as input to your lettings predicate

Comment: you're very welcome. If you want to give your saved searches functionality a try and if you get stuck then start a new question and then put the link in here so I am alerted to it

Comment: sorry, one last thing - now that your favourites functionality is working, it's probably neater to put that in a function in your viewModel and pass in your letting object from your heart button. Not essential but it's tidier that way.

Comment: i will do! sound like a plan! thanks man!

Comment: Found a new issue: Favorited posts get duplicated when i fetch the data from the server again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637159/core-data-favorited-posts-become-duplicate-when-fetching-json-again

Comment: rlong405 - you give me a good solution for saveing favorites! but now the data is ovewritened everytime i fetch again, can you give me i hint haow to fix this behaviour? thank you

Comment: Hi Marius. Do you know why my answer got unaccepted?

Comment: what do you mean? witch answeare?

Comment: Thankyou. I’m trying to build up my points so it’s nice to keep the accepted answers

Comment: Let me take a look at your other question