# Core Data - Favorited posts become duplicate when fetching JSON again

Tags: json, core-data, swiftui

In my app i fetch Json entries and save it directly in CoreData.
I added aditional Boolean IsFavorite (default False) to the entyti to let user mark as favorite and display it in a separate view.

So far so good, the problem is that when i fetch again to refres the content from updated json the Posts witch are alreadi favorite get doplicated.

This is how i fetch and save the data:

```
class JSONViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var listings: [ListingModel] = []
  //  @Published var tags :[Tags] = []
    // saving Json to Core Data...
    
    func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        listings.forEach { (data) in
            
            let entity = Listing(context: contex)
           // entity.id = Int64(data.id)
            entity.title = data.title
            entity.name = data.name
            entity.expires = data.expires
            entity.adresa = data.adresa
            entity.listingtype = data.listingtype
            entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
            entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
            entity.isFavorite = false
           
        }

        // saving all pending data at once
        
        do{
            try contex.save()             
            print("success")
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        
        let url = "https://... my json"
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.addValue("swiftui2.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "field")
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, _) in
            
            guard let jsonData = data else{return}
            
            // check for errors
            
            let response = res as! HTTPURLResponse
            // checking by status code
            
            if response.statusCode == 404 {
                print("error Api Errror")
            }
            
            // fetching JSON Data ..
            do {
                let listings = try JSONDecoder().decode([ListingModel].self, from: jsonData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  
                    self.listings = listings
                    self.saveData(contex: context)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        
        
        .resume()
    }
}
```

I mark posts as favorite with this code:

```
 Button(action: { fetchedData!.isFavorite.toggle();
                            do {
                                try context.save()   
                            }
                            catch {
                                print(error)   
                            } }) { Image(systemName: fetchedData!.isFavorite ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle")
```

On the ContentView i load latest post like this:

```
  HStack {
                    // checkin if core data exists
                    if results.isEmpty{
                        
                        if jsonModel.listings.isEmpty{
                            
                            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    ProgressView()
                        
                                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color("dinamicPillsGrass")))
                                        .scaleEffect(2, anchor: .center)
                                        // fetching data
                                        .onAppear(perform: {
                                            jsonModel.fetchData(context: context)
                                            
                                    })
                                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            }.modifier(cardHeight())
                            
                            // when array is clear indicator appears
                            // as result data is fetched again
                        }
                        else{
                            
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                
                                
                                ForEach(jsonModel.listings,id: \.self){listing in
                                    NavigationLink (destination: CardDetailView(listing: listing)) {
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            CardViewOrizontal(listing: listing)
                                        }
                                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                    // display fetched Json Data..
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    else{
                        // results.prefix(?) unde ? cata articole sa arate
                       HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(results.prefix(10)){listing in
                               
                                NavigationLink (destination: CardDetailView(fetchedData: listing)) {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                        CardViewOrizontal(fetchedData: listing)
                                    }
                                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 15)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
   
                    }
                    // update finish
                    
                }.padding(.top, 10)
```

And i update the data like this:
Note: i also check for Internet connection.

```
                Button(action: {

                    // clearing data in core data..

                    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
                      //
                        do{
                        
                            jsonModel.listings.removeAll()
**// This code is deleteing all the saved posts - also the favorite ones**                            
//                      results.forEach { (listing) in
//                                context.delete(listing)
//                                }
 
**// this code is duplicating only the favorite posts**
                            results.forEach { (listing) in

                                if  listing.isFavorite.self == false {
                                    context.delete(listing)
                                    jsonModel.listings.removeAll()
                                }
                                else {
                                    jsonModel.fetchData(context: context)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            try context.save()
                        }
                        catch{
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        print("Network is connected")
                        self.isError = false
               
                    } else {

                        print("Network is not connected")
                        self.isError = true
                    }
 
                }, label: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down")
                            .modifier(textSectionIcon())
                        Text("Update")
                            .modifier(textSectionTagline())
                    }
                    .padding(5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    .background(Color("blueLeading"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .modifier(shadowPills())
                }).alert(isPresented: $isError) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Network is not connected"),
                          message: Text("WiFi or Cellular not availible. You can still browse offline content!"),
                          dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
```

How can i update the fetching withowt duplicating the favorited posts?

Comment: It’s quite obvious, when a post is not a favorite you delete it but if it is a favorite you do not (which is good) but instead you download and inserts _all_ post into Core Data. And you do this for every favorite, so with 2 favorites you will actually download the posts twice and end up with triplicate favorites and duplicate non favorites in your storage. You need to rethink how fetchData should work and also rethink how to call it, right now it is too crude. Perhaps check if a post already exists before inserting it.

Comment: Hi. What value in the JSON are you going to use to determine whether that listing already exists in your core data? I see you have ID commented out. Can that be re introduced?

Comment: Hi rlong405 - please see the update. thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used
Constrains by id
and introduced:

```swift
 container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

`Now the data is unique, next issue is that the favorites are now getting wipped when i fetch agian!

New question here: [Update CoreData when fetch again from online Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692942/update-coredata-when-fetch-again-from-online-json?noredirect=1#comment117898376_66692942)